# Detect when screen is locked UWP

Tags: c#, windows, win-universal-app, lockscreen

How can I detect if the screen is locked in UWP apps?

When screen is locked, suspension of app occurs and I need to put some different code in case of locking screen.

Comment: The system is only going to send you *one* suspension notification. 1) Switching to desktop, 2) locking the screen and 3) the system entering a low power state are all events that can cause suspension to run. Since (1) and (2) can occur together, you'd not get a chance to run this "different code" since you won't be notified of (2). Since (2) and (3) can occur together, you'll run your "different code" and then not have a chance to run the "normal code" you'd have run for (3). I'd suggest rethinking the need for this "different code".

Comment: Use a background task with the `UserNotPresent` trigger condition.

Answer (score 1):

**You will find your answer here:**
https://developerinsider.co/prevent-the-screen-from-locking-on-uwp/

For those that are not looking for a link to another post that could, or could not, potentially be helpful here is the summary

**The code you would use is**

```
var displayRequest = new DisplayRequest();
displayRequest.RequestActive(); //to request keep display on     
displayRequest.RequestRelease(); //to release request of keep display on
```

**Things to keep in mind are**

1. Use display requests only when required, that is, times when no user
   input is expected but the display should remain on. For example,
   during full screen presentations or when the user is reading an
   e-book.
2. Release each display request as soon as it is no longer required.
3. Release all display requests when the app is suspended. If the display is still required to remain on, the app can create a new display request when it is reactivated.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't exactly detect when a user activates the lockscreen, but you can detect changes in the lifecycle. This way you can detect when a user suspends your app.

For information about the lifecycle: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/app-lifecycle