# How to know whether the windows screen is locked or not from Universal Windows App(UWP). I s there any API or way?

Tags: uwp, win-universal-app, uwp-xaml, windows-10-universal, windows-community-toolkit

[Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36938363/detect-when-screen-is-locked-uwp)

and other example: 
[does this solution work for uwp? Or it's only for desktop apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54742257/computer-status-sleep-hibernate-locked-etc-windows-10)

"An app is also suspended when the lock screen appears as long as no extended execution session, etc. is active in that app.

When an app is suspended, it invokes the Application.Suspending event. Visual Studio’s UWP project templates provide a handler for this event called OnSuspending in App.xaml.cs. Prior to Windows 10, version 1607, you would put the code to save your state here. Now the recommendation is to save your state when you enter the background state, as described above."

As per [microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/app-lifecycle?redirectedfrom=MSDN) when the lock screen is appeared the app goes to "OnSuspending()" in App.xaml.cs.

So i guess whatever code we write to check whether screen is locked or not, should be written in "OnSuspending()".

[how can this be used to solve our problem?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.lockscreen?view=winrt-18362)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there in no such api within UWP platform could used to detect the screen locked. After check you mentioned cases link, I think you could use desktop extension to approach, and the core theory is listen the screen lock behavior by  `SystemEvents.SessionSwitch` event in desktop extension and send the flag message to UWP client with `AppSerivce`. And I have implement code sample for you, please check this [link](https://github.com/ZhuMingHao/DetectLockScreen). This code sample is made base on @Stefan's blog. For more detail please search **Global hotkey registration in UWP** blog.

```
class LockScreenAppContext : ApplicationContext
{

    private Process process = null;
    private bool LockScreenInProgress = false;

    public LockScreenAppContext()
    {
        int processId = (int)ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values["processId"];
        process = Process.GetProcessById(processId);
        process.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        process.Exited += DesktopExtensionAppContext_Exited;
        SystemEvents.SessionSwitch += new SessionSwitchEventHandler(SystemEvents_SessionSwitch);

    }

    private void SystemEvents_SessionSwitch(object sender, SessionSwitchEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.Reason)
        {

            case SessionSwitchReason.SessionLock:
                SentMessage(true);
                break;
            case SessionSwitchReason.SessionUnlock:
                SentMessage(false);
                break;
        }
    }

    private async void SentMessage(bool isLocked)
    {
        ValueSet ScreebLocked = new ValueSet();
        ScreebLocked.Add("Lock", isLocked);

        AppServiceConnection connection = new AppServiceConnection();
        connection.PackageFamilyName = Package.Current.Id.FamilyName;
        connection.AppServiceName = "LockScreenConnection";
        AppServiceConnectionStatus status = await connection.OpenAsync();
        if (status != AppServiceConnectionStatus.Success)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(status);
            Application.Exit();
        }
        connection.ServiceClosed += Connection_ServiceClosed;
        AppServiceResponse response = await connection.SendMessageAsync(ScreebLocked);
    }

    private void DesktopExtensionAppContext_Exited(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Application.Exit();
    }

    private void Connection_ServiceClosed(AppServiceConnection sender, AppServiceClosedEventArgs args)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Connection_ServiceClosed");
        LockScreenInProgress = false;
    }

}
```

Comment: Actually this project you shared in github is throwing a error like this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29671811/how-to-resolve-iasyncactionwithprogress-is-defined-in-an-assembly-that-is  . Do you have any solution for this error. Can i know what type of project that 'DesktopExtension' project is, is it a WPF?.

Comment: it's winform project.

Comment: The problem you mentioned is the solution missed `system.runtime.windowsruntime` assembly. And you could find it in this path `C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETCore\v4.5`

Comment: i added the 'system.runtime.windowsruntime' assembly as per ur instruction but still the problem is not solved. [solutions like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29671811/how-to-resolve-iasyncactionwithprogress-is-defined-in-an-assembly-that-is) are saying issue may be due to improper installation of visual studio, not sure about this. I'll check this project in another pc and update.

Comment: Please check the winform project  if  References contains yellow warning ⚠ .